# resize the same image 2 times

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation, image-uploading

I upload images with a php script and I want to be able to change the size of an image if the image is too big and then create a thumb of the same image, right now I the image is resized but the thumb is not created for some reason...no errors either.
here is the script:

```
        if($image_data['image_width'] > 1024 || $image_data['image_height'] > 768)
      {


    $config_resize = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'new_image' => "./uploads/",
            'overwrite' => true,
            'maintain_ratio' => true,
            'width' => 1024,
            'height' => 768
            );
     $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_resize);
     if(! $this->image_lib->resize())
       {
         echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
       }


    $config_thumb = array(
        'source_image' => $config_resize['source_image'],
        'new_image' => "./uploads/thumbs/",
        'maintain_ratio' => true,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 100
        );
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_thumb);

    if(! $this->image_lib->resize())
       {
         echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
       }


      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.....
.....  

    $config_thumb = array(
                'source_image' => $config_resize['source_image'],
                'new_image' => "./uploads/thumbs/",
                'maintain_ratio' => true,
                'width' => 150,
                'height' => 100
                );

$this->image_lib->initialize($config_thumb); // <--- !!!
```

and don't load a library twice